# Duplicate key error with PostgreSQL INSERT with subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql

There are some similar questions on StackOverflow, but they don't seem to exactly match my case. I am trying to bulk insert into a PostgreSQL table with composite unique constraints. I created a temporary table (`temptable`) without any constraints, and loaded the data (with possible some duplicate values) in it. So far, so good.

Now, I am trying to transfer the data to the actual table (`realtable`) with unique index. For this, I used an INSERT statement with a subquery:

```
INSERT INTO realtable 
SELECT * FROM temptable WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM realtable WHERE temptable.added_date = realtable.added_date
                              AND temptable.product_name = realtable.product_name
);
```

However, I am getting duplicate key errors:

```
ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "realtable_added_date_product_name_key"
SQL state: 23505
Detail: Key (added_date, product_name)=(20000103, TEST) already exists.
```

My question is, shouldn't the WHERE NOT EXISTS clause prevent this from happening? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `NOT EXISTS` clause only prevents rows from `temptable` conflicting with existing rows from `realtable`; it will not prevent multiple rows from `temptable` from conflicting with each other. This is because the `SELECT` is calculated once based on the initial state of `realtable`, not re-calculated after each row is inserted.

One solution would be to use a `GROUP BY` or `DISTINCT ON` in the `SELECT` query, to omit duplicates, e.g.

```
INSERT INTO realtable 
SELECT DISTINCT ON (added_date, product_name) * 
FROM temptable WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM realtable WHERE temptable.added_date = realtable.added_date
                              AND temptable.product_name = realtable.product_name
)
ORDER BY ???; -- this ORDER BY will determine which of a set of duplicates is kept by the DISTINCT ON
```